# How to ask a Catholic priest to bless something for someone else?

Tags: catholicism, blessings, rome

So, I am traveling abroad from my home country and will have the opportunity to visit some really cool, super old churches and cathedrals in Europe. I would like to bring a gift back home for a friend who is a Catholic, and I was thinking of bringing something related to the church like a rosary, etc. since I will be so close to so many important historical sites of this organization that's important to their life. I've read that when people get things like that ("sacramentals"?) they often have them blessed (?) and I think that would be something cool to have done in one of the medieval/Renaissance churches I'll visit, it would make it a more unique gift.

I have access to translation tools/know enough Spanish and Italian to physically ask a priest to, but is there like a proper way to approach him or an appropriate time? Should I specify that it's not going to be mine, but a gift? Would he care that I am not religious? And for my friend, are there any steps I would need to take to avoid delegitimizing the blessing in their eyes (not touching item directly afterwards, not taking an active role in the blessing and asking a nearby Catholic to deal with it for me, etc.)? Thanks

Comment: Just ask a priest.

Comment: Although it's certainly OK to just ask, I'd suggest telling the priest that you're not Catholic but intend to give the item to a Catholic friend.  The reason for my suggestion has nothing to do with the blessing but with avoiding some potential awkwardness: Your asking to have something blessed would probably lead the priest to assume that you're Catholic. If he begins a conversation with you while holding that assumption, it could be awkward for both of you. So my suggestion is intended only to avoid that possibility.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That was worth putting into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just literally ask the priest to bless that thing you want a blessing on (which will become a *sacramental* after it's being blessed). You do not have to mention that it'll be for someone else as it won't change anything. As your friend, just tell him that your gift is blessed already and I guess he'll know what to do with it? :-) Cheers and God bless!